# C# Entity Framework code-first relations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-relationship

I have `UserDetail` model which contains some properties and I want to add known and unknown languages list to user.

I have a question: how I can do it? Firstly I think that I need to create two tables `unknownLanguages` and `knownLanguages` and a relation one to many, but both tables have the same properties like `Value` and `Name` so maybe a better solution is create one table `Languages` with relation many to many but then how I can divide properties into known and unknown?

I tried do this like this:

Language Model:

```
public class Language
{
    public Language()
    {
        this.UserDetails = new HashSet<UserDetail>();
    }

    public int LanguageId { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserDetail> UserDetails { get; set; }
}
```

UserDetail model:

```
public class UserDetail
{
    public UserDetail()
    {
        this.Languages = new HashSet<Language>();
    }

    [Key, ForeignKey("User")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string About { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Language> Languages { get; set; }
}
```

but relation many to many was not created besides I don't know how I can add known and unknown property.

Any suggestions?

Regards

Comment: You want to add two foreign keys (relations) having names unknowLanguages and knownLanguages?

Comment: Ordinarily, I'd think you would not have "unknown languages" stored in the database at all. Any language which isn't in the list of known languages is by definition unknown. Or is the distinction between "not filled in" and "filled in as unknown" important to you? And what do you want to do about the possibility of languages existing both as "known" and as "unknown" at the same time in the database?

Answer (score 1):

Since the knowing of a language is on the mapping to the user, for example - there's one English, and only ever one English, but several users may know English, and several users may not know English. Therefore, you are describing how the users use the language English. It wouldn't follow normalization to have a modified version of English for each user - as there is only one English.

Therefore, I would place those details in a mapping table. You can take control of the generated many-to-many mapping table like so (instead of allowing EF to automatically create one for you):

```
public class UserDetailLanguage
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }

    public virtual UserDetail UserDetail { get; set; }
    public Int32 UserDetailId { get; set; }

    public virtual Language Language { get; set; }
    public Int32 LanguageId { get; set; }

    public Boolean IsKnown { get; set; }
}
public class UserDetail
{
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<UserDetailLanguage> UserDetailLanguages { get; set; }
    ...
}
public class Language
{
    ...
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserDetailLanguage> UserDetailLanguages { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

EDIT:

To show this is use:

```
//find all known languages for a user
userDetail.UserDetailLanguages.Where( c => c.IsKnown ).Select( c => c.Language)

//find all unknown languages for a user
userDetail.UserDetailLanguages.Where( c => !c.IsKnown ).Select( c => c.Language)

//find all known languages for all users
_dbContext.Set<UserDetailLanguage>().Where( c => c.IsKnown ).Select( c => c.Language)

//find all unknown languages for all users
_dbContext.Set<UserDetailLanguage>().Where( c => !c.IsKnown ).Select( c => c.Language)
```

Comment: It's exactly what I want to do, thanks I will try use this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can have one base class `Language` and derive two class from that `knownLanguages` and `unknownLanguages`
Have a look at here https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines